# Select the first occurrence of each id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 1 | Banana |
| 1 | Guava |
| 2 | Cassava |
| 2 | Carrot |
| 2 | Potato |
| 3 | Almond |
| 3 | Soybeans |
| 3 | Peanuts |

I want to select only the first one from each id

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Cassava |
| 3 | Almond |

What's the query like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: `I want to select only the first one` ... there needs to be a third column which records which one is the "first."  Your question, in its current form, is not answerable.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this way

```
SELECT id, name FROM table_name GROUP BY id ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal by using row_number(). You can check my query in db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g4MrUTTTGDFfqjAKYnkFxn/1

```
WITH CTE as
(
 SELECT id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY null) as rowNumber FROM Fruits
)
SELECT id, name FROM CTE WHERE rowNumber IN(SELECT min(rowNumber) FROM CTE Group by id)
```